# How to convert int list list list to (int * int) list in f#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

If I want to Convert a list [[[0; 5]; [1; 5]; [2; 3]]] to a tuple list [(0, 5); (1, 5); (2, 3)] using f# or pattern matching in f# please how do I do this?

Comment: Why did you just delete your median question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245159/calculate-the-median-of-values

Answer (score 3):

I would flatten the outer level of the list (by concatenating the second level lists), then transform the inner lists into tuples using `map`:

```
let transform lst =
    lst
    |> List.concat
    |> List.map (function
        | [a; b] -> (a, b)
        | _ -> failwith "Incorrect list syntax")
```

Comment: Thanks dumetrulo your reply was helpful.